# 'NoneType' and 'NoneType' при сложении списков из других функций

Tags: python, список

Почему-то выдает ошибку 'NoneType' для списков если их вызывать из других функций. 
Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться. 
line 35, in all_flat
    map_for_all_flat = map_for_first_room + map_for_second_room + map_for_third_room + map_for_fourth_room
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'NoneType' and 'NoneType'

```
go_down = ['DOWN']

go_up = ['UP',]

go_right = ['RIGHT']

go_left = ['LEFT']

go_down_five_times = go_down*5 
go_right_three_times = go_right*3 
go_left_two_times = go_left*2 
go_right_two_times = go_right*2
go_up_five_times = go_up*5
go_up_left_up = go_up + go_left + go_up
go_up_four_times = go_up*4

def first_room():
    map_for_first_room = []
    map_for_first_room = go_down_five_times + go_right_three_times + go_up + go_left_two_times + go_up + go_right_two_times + go_up + go_left_two_times + go_up + go_right_three_times 

def second_room():
    map_for_second_room = []
    map_for_second_room = go_right + go_down_five_times + go_right + go_up_five_times + go_right + go_down_five_times + go_right

def third_room(): 
    map_for_third_room = []
    map_for_third_room = go_right_two_times + go_up_left_up + go_right + go_up_left_up + go_right_three_times + go_down_five_times + go_right

def fourth_room():
    map_for_fourth_room = []
    map_for_fourth_room = go_right + go_up_five_times + go_right + go_down_five_times + go_right + go_up_four_times

def all_flat(map_for_first_room, map_for_second_room, map_for_third_room, map_for_fourth_room):
    map_for_all_flat = []
    map_for_all_flat = map_for_first_room + map_for_second_room + map_for_third_room + map_for_fourth_room


def print(map_for_all_flat): 
    print(map_for_all_flat)


if __name__ == '__main__': 
    first_room()
    second_room()
    third_room()
    fourth_room()
    map_for_first_room = first_room()
    map_for_second_room = second_room()
    map_for_third_room = third_room()
    map_for_fourth_room = fourth_room()
    all_flat(map_for_first_room, map_for_second_room, map_for_third_room, map_for_fourth_room)
    map_for_all_flat = all_flat(map_for_first_room, map_for_second_room, map_for_third_room, map_for_fourth_room)
    print(map_for_all_flat)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

выражения такого вида `map_for_first_room = first_room()`
для функций токого вида:

```
def first_room():
    map_for_first_room = []
    map_for_first_room = go_down_five_times + go_right_three_times + go_up + go_left_two_times + go_up + go_right_two_times + go_up + go_left_two_times + go_up + go_right_three_times
```

приводят к присваиванию `None` переменным `map_for_first_room` и т.д.
Функции не возвращающие значения в Python по умолчанию вазвращают `None`.
Используйте `return`:

```
def first_room():
    map_for_first_room = []
    map_for_first_room = go_down_five_times + go_right_three_times + go_up + go_left_two_times + go_up + go_right_two_times + go_up + go_left_two_times + go_up + go_right_three_times 
    return map_for_first_room
```

Comment: Ааа, точно. Спасибо.

Comment: @MrStepin и в общем можно сократить до `return lst_1 + lst_2 + ... + lst_n`.  Пожалуйста.